# Spring Boot Eureka server dashboard error

Tags: java, spring, maven, netflix-eureka

I have been trying to learn microservice development with spring boot and netflix oss.

I have been stuck with this eureka dashboard error for two days now and i can not seem to fix it. please help.
I have a single discovery client instance and the server is in standalone mode
[This is how the dashboard looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR1Dn.png)

Here is the server main class

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer

public class EurekaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

conf files application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: ${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EurekaApplication</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you use the spring boot parent pom instead of spring cloud's one?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I used spring initializr to create the project, might that be the source of the problem?

Comment: Don't know, but I would give it a try. Also you are using the Brixton version, which is currently in beta stage. You could try with with Angel instead. Anyway, it would be good to report any kind of problem with Brixton to the Spring guys.

Comment: @XtremeBiker thank you for pointing me towards the answer, Angel.SR6 threw an exception that Brixton did not throw, which led me to nail the culprit. I have answered below

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my application.yml file
serviceUrl property value had a typo. I forgot to include http:// before the eureka.instance.hostname

Here is the fixed yaml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

It was never an issue with Brixton.RC1

Answer (score 0):

No need to add spring-milestone as dependency as you are using release version.Its used only when you are using M version.See spring boot official doc for more details.Your code looks fine.It should work.Specify the error you are getting.Here is pom.xml and .yml file i am using which works.:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org.springframework.samples.service.service
    microservice-demo
    1.1.0.RELEASE
    jar

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <!-- Stand-alone RESTFul application for testing only -->
    <start-class>io.pivotal.microservices.services.Main</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Data common components -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Testing starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Data JPA Repository support -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- In-memory database for testing/demos -->
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Eureka service registration -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## Configure this Discovery Server

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

```
  server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port

# Discovery Server Dashboard uses FreeMarker.  Don't want Thymeleaf        templates
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    enabled: false     # Disable Thymeleaf
```